# Iam having a runtime error while running my selection short program in java

Tags: java, exception, eclipse-plugin, runtime-error, selection-sort

I was doing this shorting program of selection short and when I run it I got this exception which I am unable to figure out why I am having it, (the software I am using is Eclipse)
here is the code

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the length of matrix");
int len=sc.nextInt();
int a[]=new int[len];
System.out.println("Enter the series");
for(int k=0; k<len; k++) {
    a[k] = sc.nextInt();
}

for(int i=0;i<len-1;i++) {
    int minind=i;
    for(int j=0; j<len-1-i; j++) {
        if(a[j] < a[minind]) {
            minind=j;
        }
    
        int temp=a[i];
        a[i]=a[minind];
        a[minind]=a[temp];
    }
}
System.out.println("Shorted array is ");
for(int item : a) {
    System.out.print(item + " ");
}
```

here is my input

Enter the length of matrix

4

Enter the series

4 5 6 1

here is the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 4
    at arrays.Selection_short.main(Selection_short.java:27)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change below line and try.

> a[minind]=a[temp];

to

> a[minind]=temp;

Let me know if this solved ArrayIndexOutofBoundException.

Comment: Thnx it solved the exception